# IndexOutOfBound while recursively summing array by halves

Tags: java, recursion

I've been practicing my recursion, and one of the exercises I'm trying is to get the sum of an array by splitting it in halves and then getting down to the single element and adding its value to an accumulator which gets returned.

Code:

```
public static int arrayValuesSum(int[] arr) {
    return arrayValuesSumHelper(arr,0);
}

public static int arrayValuesSumHelper(int[] arr, int acc) {
    if (arr.length == 0)
        acc += 0;

    else if (arr.length == 1)
        acc += arr[0];

    else if(arr.length == 2) {
        int[] arrOne = new int[] {arr[0]};
        int[] arrTwo = new int[] {arr[1]};
        return arrayValuesSumHelper(arrOne, acc) + arrayValuesSumHelper(arrTwo, acc);
    }

    else {
        int[] arrOne = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr[0], arr[(arr.length/2)]);
        int[] arrTwo = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr[((arr.length)/2)], arr[(arr.length)]);
        return arrayValuesSumHelper(arrOne, acc) + arrayValuesSumHelper(arrTwo, acc);
    }
    return acc;
}
```

However, when the array size is bigger than two, I get `indexOutOfBounds` exceptions, and I know that `copyofRange(int startInc, int endExc)` is [a,b). I've played around with that a lot. Why is this not working? Both with array sizes with only even factors and those without?

Comment: The exception will tell you exactly what is wrong and in which line of code. Use it!

Comment: I've tried putting a breakpoint in @john3136 but I need help! Or I wouldn't be here.

Comment: you don't need a breakpoint. You said you got an IndexOutOfBounds exception. That will tell you the line of code, the index you tried to access and the maximum allowed index. That is all you need to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation with respect to recursion is to keep it simple and let the recursion do the work.  This is a perfect example.  You've made the solution too complicated and are chasing bugs that shouldn't have even happened.  Consider:

```
public static int arrayValuesSum(int[] array) {
    return arrayValuesSumRecursive(array, 0, array.length);
}

public static int arrayValuesSumRecursive(int[] array, int start, int length) {

    if (length == 0)
        return 0;

    if (length == 1)
        return array[start];

    int half = length / 2;

    return arrayValuesSumRecursive(array, start, half) + arrayValuesSumRecursive(array, start + half, length - half);
}
```

No need to waste time and space copying, and recopying, the array.